# Suppressing nested exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception

In the `except` clause of a `try...except` block, is there any way to mark the current exception as handled, so if another exception is raised in the except block, it doesn't link the new exception to the old one?

Example:

```
from time import sleep

def connect(server):
    print("Attempting to connecting to", server)
    sleep(2)
    raise ConnectionRefusedError("Couldn't connect")
    print("Connected to", server)

try:
    conn = connect('main-server')
except ConnectionRefusedError as connection_refused:
    # connection_refused.handled = True
    conn = connect('backup-server')
```

This produces:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#37>", line 2, in <module>
>     conn = connect('main-server')
>   File "<pyshell#26>", line 2, in connect
>     raise ConnectionRefusedError("Couldn't connect")
> ConnectionRefusedError: Couldn't connect
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#37>", line 4, in <module>
>     conn = connect('backup-server')
>   File "<pyshell#26>", line 2, in connect
>     raise ConnectionRefusedError("Couldn't connect")
> ConnectionRefusedError: Couldn't connect
> ```

I'd like to mark the first exception as handled, so that the second exception doesn't link to the first with the "*During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred*" ceremony.

I realize in this simple example, I can do this by creating a flag condition, exiting the `except` clause, testing the flag, and resuming the recovery code.

```
try:
    conn = connect('main-server')
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    conn = None

if not conn:
    conn = connect('backup-server')
```

Or using a `for...else` construct:

```
for server in ('main-server', 'backup-server'):
    try:
        conn = connect(server)
        break
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        continue
else:
    raise ConnectionRefusedError("Couldn't connect to any server")
```

Finally, I know I can wrap my exception handler in a `try...except` block, and use `raise...from None` to hide the first exception.

```
try:
    conn = connect('main-server')
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    try:
        conn = connect('backup-server')
    except ConnectionRefusedError as nested:
        raise nested from None
```

But I'm not looking for any "restructure the code" solutions, and I'd rather not use the `try ... except ... try ... except ... raise ... from None`, catching exception simply to raise it again.  I'm curious if there is anything I can place at this point:

```
except ConnectionRefusedError as connection_refused:
    # connection_refused.handled = True
```

which can flag the exception as being completely handled.

Comment: the original code raises two exceptions, one in try and other in except block... you also seem well informed about the possibilities in python... and you do not want yo restructure initial code and make the chain of exceptions resolve on its own. that's a deadlock. )

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Well, I like to think I’m well informed, but there is always more to learn.  I’m not opposed to restructuring my code; I just wanted to avoid answers which “solve” the problem by avoiding the problem.  I‘m hoping for a clean, one-line `del connection_refused` or `sys.exc_clear()` or some other magic incantation which I’m currently not informed of.